# Build failed in Unity Flutter integration

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am trying to integrate Flutter with Unity using the `flutter_unity_widget`, but I am getting the following error message when I try to build my project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Users\JAYATI RAVAL\Documents\ForARtisticHome\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 453
```

**What went wrong:**
A problem occurred configuring project: `cloud_firestore`

**For input string:**

```
"C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022"
```

**I have tried the following solutions:**
Checking the path to the Unity SDK.
Cleaning my Flutter project and rebuilding it.
Restarting my computer.

I have a "view in AR" button in UI to initiate the AR experience in unity.